# LINQ - How can I give a child object in a select statement a reference to its parent?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
        List<FundEntity> entities = this.tFunds
            .Select(f => new FundEntity() {
               ID = f.fundID,
               Name = f.name,
               CapitalCalls = f.tCapitalCalls
                    .Select(cc => new CapitalCall() {
                        ID =  cc.capitalCallID,
                        Description = cc.description,
                        FundEntity = // Should be the newly created Fund Entity object
                    }).ToList()                   
            }).ToList();
```

I would like the each Capitalcall object to have a reference back to its FundEntity. Is this possible without creating a loop and setting each one manually?

Comment: Is `f` not a legal variable in that context?

Comment: good question, but f is not the right type, that is of tFund (a data class generated class). II need it to be of type FundEntity - a model that uses its data

Answer (score 7):

```
List<FundEntity> entities = this.tFunds
        .Select(f => 
        {
           var parent = new FundEntity() {
               ID = f.fundID,
               Name = f.name,
               };
           parent.CapitalCalls = f.tCapitalCalls
                    .Select(cc => new CapitalCall() {
                    ID =  cc.capitalCallID,
                    Description = cc.description,
                    FundEntity =parent // Should be the newly created Fund Entity object
                });
            return parent;
        }.ToList()                   
        ).ToList();
```

That should give you the reference.

Comment: oh wow. i usually write in vb.net, had no idea you can do multiline inline functions in c#.

Comment: As Tomas noted this probably won't translate to SQL but in that case you could always just pull back the entities in their table forms, and then do this in the translation to the entity.

Answer (score 2):

Is this LINQ in memory or LINQ to Entities/SQL?

- In the first case, you can just create the entity and then set its `CapitalCalls` property imperatively (as in the example from Stephan)
- In the second case, I'm afraid there is no way to do this in the LINQ query (because you cannot reference to the object that you're creating while it is being created, but you cannot use multiple statements, because the translator doesn't support that). However you could easily modify your database or Entity model to contain the reference you need...